# How to create user in Centos 5.6

Tags: linux, centos5

I have a VPS with Centos 5.6 running on it. I have WHM gui running and create users but they have to be associated with domains. In a terminal can I create a user that is not associated with a domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can, instructions can be found here:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-users-add.html